# The requested resource does not support http method 'GET' ASP MVC

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I have a MVC api and are using controllers to access my data but I am using ajax and knockoutjs to call my method but I am getting the following error: The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'. I have tried using [HttpGET] at the top of my controller method but it still does not work. I am not sure how to solve this problem.

Knock ViewModel doing my api call:

```
vm = {
        Data: ko.observable(),
        Bound: 0,

        Load: function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "../api/adusers",
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                success: function (result) {
                    vm.Data(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(ko.mapping.fromJS(result)));

                    if (!vm.Bound) {
                        ko.applyBindings(vm, document.getElementById("form1"));
                        $('#tableUsers').show();
                        vm.Bound = true;
                    }
                },
                error: function (xhr, status) {
                    alert(status + " - " + xhr.responseText);
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

API Controller:

```
public class ADUsersController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public static List<Models.Users> GetADUsers()
    {
        return AD.GetUsers(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NETBios"]
            , System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Container"]
            , System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ADServerUN"]
            , System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ADServerPW"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm quite sure that `static` controller actions are not supported. Try to remove the `static` from your `GetADUsers` method!

Comment: Thank you so much I never thought of that. It works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared your controller action as `static` which is obviously not supported. Controller actions are instance methods. So make sure you declared your action as an instance method:

```
public class ADUsersController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public List<Models.Users> GetADUsers()
    {
        return AD.GetUsers(
            System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NETBios"], 
            System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Container"], 
            System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ADServerUN"], 
            System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ADServerPW"]
        );
    }
}
```